# Revoking Runtime Permission in Android

Tags: java, android, android-permissions

For API level >= 23, is there any way to revoke a previously granted permission programmatically without removing it from manifest? Is there a method in the API to do that?

Comment: There might be one in the device admin or device owner APIs. Otherwise, I do not think that such an option exists.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such a method. Users can revoke granted permissions only from Settings -> Applications -> your_application -> Permissions.